# Serverless: Running "serverless" installed locally (in service node_modules)

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab-ci, serverless-framework

I am trying to deploy a service to aws using serverless. I am deploying it using gitlab cicd instead of doing it locally. Initially my serverless version was latest(had not mentioned any specific version) but then when I pushed my code to gitlab and i got few errors in the pipeline as the latest version is not stable. So had to change the version to a stable version. Now when i pushed my code changes to gitlab, my deployment failed and i got

> > Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
> > Cannot run local installation of the Serverless Framework by the outdated global version.   Please upgrade via:
> > npm install -g serverless   Note: Latest release can run any version of the locally installed Serverless Framework.

I dont want to upgrade my serverless version.

in my gitlab-ci.yml i have changed

```
- npm install -g serverless
```

to this

```
- npm install -g serverless@2.69.1
```

Is there any way I can fix this ?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It's not saying that you should upgrade your global serverless version, but instead your local serverless version. It seems to me that you have serverless installed locally through npm and then the global version, so you might want you look at the version of serverless in your package.json

Answer (score 1):

in your case, the most likely reason for that is the fact that you have a local installation of Serverless or some of the plugins/your other dependencies have Serverless v3 in peer dependencies and install it by default in npm@7 and higher.
To resolve it, either remove local installation or pin the version of the locally installed Serverless (in `devDependencies` of `package.json` of your project).

Answer (score 0):

`./node_modules/.bin/sls deploy` does the trick.

However, the proper answer is in the docs:

> There are 2 scenarios:
>
> - Using v3 globally, and v2 in specific projects.
>   This is the simplest. Upgrade the global version to v3, and install v2 in specific projects (via NPM). The serverless command will automatically run the correct version (v3 can run v2).
> - Using v2 globally, and v3 in specific projects.
>   To achieve that, install v3 in specific projects (via NPM). Then, use serverless for v2 projects, and npx serverless for v3 projects.

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/upgrading-v3#using-v2-and-v3-in-different-projects