# Detected unrecognized CLI options: "--profile"

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, gitlab, serverless-framework

I am trying to deploy my code to AWS using Serverless through Gitlab cicd. All stages have been passed but when it comes to deployment stage, I get the following error.

> Detected unrecognized CLI options: "--profile".

I have defined profile in my serverless, not sure what's going wrong. I tried changing my serverless from latest to stable but then i got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71937166/serverless-running-serverless-installed-locally-in-service-node-modules).

Does anyone know what has to be done here exactly ?
Any help would be appreciated, Thank you !!

Answer (score 3):

Use property `--aws-profile` instead `--profile`.

Reference: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/credentials/

Looks like they have changed the variables naming in Serverless v3.

Comment: I degraded my version to stable version and got rid of the error.  I use --aws-profile while deploying locally, but in gitlab cicd pipeline, --aws-profile gives error too. Hopefully this would help someone